# How to Find if String exist in Array to Make Username and Password Program in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, passwords

```
//Username  and Password
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void
main ()
{
  const char *arr[] =
    { "lonely_wolf69", "Alpha_male420", "jojo_rabbit77",
"secrethitleradmirer" };
  char a, *pass = "steverogersrox", n;
  int i, flag = 0;


  printf ("Enter Username: ");
  scanf ("%c", &a);

  if (memchr (arr, a, sizeof (arr)))
    {
      for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
      printf (" \n Enter Password: ");
      scanf ("%c", &n);
      if (n == *pass)
        {
          printf ("\n Login Successfull");
          break;
        }
      else
        {
          printf ("Wrong Password, Try Again.");
          flag++;
        }
    }


    }
  else
    printf ("User Not Found");

  if (flag == 3)
    printf ("\n You have been Blocked out of the system.");

}
```

Whatever I am entering, its Just Showing User Not Found.
Note: I know.....very tedious....but looking to understand the concept first and clean up later, also any smarter Ideas are always encouraged.

Comment: `memchr (arr, a, sizeof (arr))` makes no sense. Your looking for a character among the *pointers* in the array `arr`.

Comment: `scanf ("%c", &a);` is wrong, unless you're expecting usernames of only 1 char long. You should do something like `char a[30]; scanf("%29s", a);` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 3 Excruciating Days.....I Finally did it. Small But I'm really Proud

```
''''

    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    
    void
    main ()
    {
      int attempts = 3, i, n = 0;
      char user[20], pass[20];
      const char *user_list[] =
        { "lonely_wolf69", "Alpha_male420", "jojo_rabbit77",
        "secrethitleradmirer", "johnlennonbutpoor"
      };
    
    
      printf ("Enter Your Username: ");
      scanf ("%s", user);
    
    
    //for all elements of the list check if name present
    
      for (i = 0; i < sizeof (user_list) / sizeof (user_list[1]); i++)  //size of finds the lenght of array
        {
          if (strcmp (user, user_list[i]) == 0)
        {
          n = 1;
        }
        }
    
    
    
      if (n == 1)
        {
          while (attempts > 0)
        {
          printf ("\n Enter Password: ");
          scanf ("%s", pass);
    
          if (strcmp (pass, "love") == 0)
            {
              printf ("Login Successful");
              break;
            }
          else
            {
              attempts--;
              if (attempts == 0)
            break;
              printf ("\n Wrong Password! Try Again. %d attempt(s) left",
                  attempts);
            }
        }
        }
    
    
      if (n != 1)
        printf ("User Not Found.");
    
    
    
      if (attempts == 0)
        printf ("You Have Been Blocked");
    }
    
    ''''
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding:

```
printf ("Enter Username: ");
scanf ("%c", &a); /* this only reads one char */
```

You declared `a` to be of type `char`, but you need an array of characters here, unless you expect the usernames to be of 1 `char`.

You have the same problem here:

```
printf (" \n Enter Password: ");
scanf ("%c", &n);. /* so does this */
```

Regarding:

```
n == *pass /* compares two characters */
```

Once you fix the aforementioned problems, use `strcmp` to compare strings. `==` only compares the pointers.

Regarding:

```
memchr (arr, a, sizeof (arr));
```

*The `memchr()` function scans the initial n bytes of the memory
area pointed to by s for the first instance of c.*

Why do you wish to search for a `char` instead of a string?

Use `strcmp` in a loop, or sort the array in ascending order and use `bsearch`.

Comment: Hello, I've just started Learning C, I know a bit of python.....but the concept of arrays are just too much. Tutorials aren't helping, and I do think it's easier for me to remeber if I brute force my way through. So can you pls write me the correct thing?

Comment: Instead of tutorials, pick up a good C book and work your way through it. C is not a language you can just brute-force through. Giving you a solution wouldn't help anyone, but I did point the mistakes you did. And I'm sure you can take something from that.